# Order by with Collate clause | Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I don't want to use array sorting on the web server it should be done on SQL server.

Microsoft does not support query(in EF) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table_1]
ORDER BY [Table_1].field
COLLATE SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_Cp1_CI_AS
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advice...

Comment: This looks like a valid SQL statement to me.  What happens when you run it?

Comment: I want to make this SQL query when I'm getting Entity Set for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Entity Framework *does* support a COLLATE clause in an [ORDER BY in Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399723.aspx). I'm not aware of any way to do it with LINQ to Entities. Indeed, I don't know how to do it with *any* LINQ provider. I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Very very bad. I found hack solution, but I still hope that Microsoft will support this in the feature.

Comment: Entity SQL isn't a kludgy solution. It is supported and works fine. But, yes, it would be nice to have similar support in LINQ.